# Double clicking Unix Executable file is different from running it from terminal

Tags: macos, unix, executable-jar, .app

I'm trying to create `.app` package that contains jdk, jar and shell script, basically I'm trying to run jar inside `.app`.

My contents inside `.app` looks like this (app has same name as unix executable):

```
.
├── MacOS
│   └── AppName
├── app
│   └── myapp.jar
└── jdk
```

AppName, if we give it `.sh` extension and look into it, looks like this

```
#!/bin/zsh

../jdk/bin/java -jar ../app/myapp.jar
```

If I run this file executable file from terminal with `./AppName` it works without any problems. But if I just double click it, it doesn't work saying `no such file or directory: ../jdk/bin/java`.

I believe it should work with double clicking in order to work with `.app`, because other `.app`-s work like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative path names like `../jdk/bin/java` are relative to the current working directory, not to the location of the script.

You can reproduce the problem in the terminal when your working directory is not `MacOS` but, e.g., the parent directory, and you start the application as `MacOS/AppName`.

A possible solution might be

```
#!/bin/zsh

SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname $0)

"$SCRIPTDIR"/../jdk/bin/java -jar "$SCRIPTDIR"/../app/myapp.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Correct me if I'm wrong but as I've seen when double clicking `.app` in finder, the current working directory in executable is assumed to be `$HOME`, because if I make that assumption in script then relative paths work, but it's a bad solution as it assumes that I'm having my app in `/Applications`. Your suggested solution is generic and very nice, though, ty.